# Sourcify is failing to verify a contract that is verified on etherscan. Why?

Tags: polygon, contract-verification, sourcify

This contract address:

> 0xA933268b812f97Cf623Af8d16780e45880fa1af2

Is verified on mumbai polygonscan.  When I try to verify it with sourcify, I get this error:

```
invalid json response body at https://api-testnet.polygonscan.com/api?module=contract&action=getsourcecode&address=0xA933268b812f97Cf623Af8d16780e45880fa1af2&apikey=5M8VXYQAYZ5SE1KGWSCBV942EBX7P4IUGG reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

Has anyone experienced this before?  Any idea what might be wrong with either sourcify or polygonscan for this one?

Answer (score 0):

Sourcify developer here  Just seeing this..

It was probably a server hiccup. Sorry that this happened. I was able to verify it easily using "Import from Etherscan" in our UI: https://repo.sourcify.dev/contracts/full_match/80001/0xA933268b812f97Cf623Af8d16780e45880fa1af2/

If you have questions feel free to reach out at

- Matrix: https://matrix.to/#/#ethereum_source-verify:gitter.im
- Discord: https://discord.com/invite/6aqd9cfZ9s